# Is there a way to connect windows machine as jenkins agent without using java?

Tags: java, jenkins

I got this request from a client and they want to connect windows machines as a jenkins agent without using java or JNLP.

I know that there are 3 ways in which u can connect a windows agent -

1. Using SSH
2. Using WebSocket transport
3. Using the Java Web start service install

All of these methods use java in the background to connect the agent to jenkins.

I know that jenkins is built using java and connecting agent to it requires java to be installed but i am looking for a detailed explanation to convince the client.

Comment: From the [Jenkins Agent Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/): **The agents require a Java installation and a network connection to the Jenkins controller.** IMHO there is nothing to add to that statement.

Comment: The Java process is the actual agent which communicates with the Jenkins master and coordinates all the events on the slave. Without the Java process, the master has nothing to command / control.

Comment: If you goal is to simple (deploy) files to a Windows machine, then you do not need the Jenkins agent, but some other mechanism, which may move (files) over SSH.

Comment: You could offer to implement a non-java agent for Jenkins, but probably won't be as cross-platform compatible as the java agent.

Comment: No Java - no Jenkins. But there are alternative CICD tools. Find out whether Nojava or Jenkins is more important to your customer.